# Maven - pom file - Artifact not being created

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, maven-profiles

I have a pom file that is triggered by jenkins and is being used twice, every time on a different machine(docker container) with different compilers(to be built for different linux distributions).

In order to get those 2 different builds as artifacts, and with different names, I'm trying to use profiles and set the classifier of the artifact with different values.

It seems though that the artifacts are not being created for some reason, and I don't know why.

I'm not sure I configured the profiles correctly and I also have the 'attach-to-artifact' in an execution block of its own and I don't know if it's right.

Any help would be much appreciated.

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>XXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>XXXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXXXXX</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>

<scm>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://XXXXXX</developerConnection>
</scm>

<properties>
    <revision>1.0.0-1-SNAPSHOT</revision>
</properties>

<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <exec executable="sh" failonerror="true">
                                <arg line="build.sh"/>
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-test-package</id>
                    <phase>prepare-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${env.ESX_COMPILATION}</skip>
                        <target>
                            <exec executable="sh" failonerror="true">
                                <arg line="tests.sh"/>
                            </exec>
                            <attachartifact file="${project.build.directory}/archive.tar.gz" type="tar.gz"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-to-artifact</id>
                    <phase>attach-artifact</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>${envClassifier}</classifier>
                        <target>
                            <attachartifact file="${project.build.directory}/archive.tar.gz" type="tar.gz"/>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>esx</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.ESX_COMPILATION</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <envClassifier>esx</envClassifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>linux</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.ESX_COMPILATION</name>
                <value>false</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <envClassifier>linux</envClassifier>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

As can be seen I'm using the 'env.ESX_COMPILATION' variable to set the profile choice which sets the 'envClassifier' variable and in the final execution block, under  and before  i set the 'classifier'. and inside target i call 'attachtoartifact'

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What is the log output? What errors do you get?

Comment: First flatten-maven-plugin is incorrectly configured ....Take a detailed look at the documentation https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html What is the purpose of your antrun plugin configuration? And why executing an external script?